# PHP table values

Tags: php

I have a question and I will try to explain the best way that I can

I have a table that show me names of accounts and each one of that accounts has it own information.
[image: Something like this]

and I'm getting that information like this

[image]

On the page "verpersonagem.php" I have this: $idaccount = $_GET['accountId'];
but the url comes like this ../verpersonagem.php?account=
Why it's not getting the value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have yo use all this echo statement
try this

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    echo '<tr>
            <th><a href="verpersonagem.php?account='. $row[0] .'"> '. $row[0] .' </a></th>
            <td>'. $row[2] .' </td>
            <td>'. $row[1] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row[3] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row[4] .'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I will change it
And about my question?

Comment: is there something i miss in your question ?

Comment: how can I get the account name to from that page to another one clicking on the name of the account

Comment: in the other account you will do this  if(!empty($_GET['account'])){
        $accountId = $_GET['account'];
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE accountID = '$accountId'";
    $row = mysqli_query($link, $query);  and complete the rest as above

Comment: I will change the original question for my code now, if you can please check it

Comment: yes . answer edited . check the updates . it should be a " after ?account='. $row[0] .' . now it should works fine .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160872/discussion-between-samehanwar-and-shwsvn).

Answer (score 1):

You should insert the href into the Table its TD instead of TH

Use a for loop instead and say count(rows)

Then $i < $rows and href=example.php?id=$i

Then use $_GET['id']
And do a database query which gets all the info about the id

Comment: Can you explain better please?

Comment: Make a for loop in php then call the table with the tabelhead called Person then add TD with a (<a href='example.php?name=test$i'>) then in the example.php: $_GET['name']; and store that in a variable then you can do database queries with the variable

Comment: <?php
   // query to database that get the amount of users 

for($i = 0; $i < count(/* amount of users */; $i++) { 
    echo '<tr>
            <th>users</th>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="example.php?name=test$i">Name $i</a></td>
</tr>
';
    }
?>

Example.php

<?php
$user = $_GET['name'];

// now use $user to get all info about this user and display it on the page
?>

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried but I couldn't make it work
The url stays like this "verpersonagem.php?ID="